# make model of array object in flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I'm try to make model array for my design table look like this. But I've no idea how to do it.

[image]

I've refer this [link](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) for my json array bellow but it give error `The json provider has syntax errors`

```
{
  "serialNumber": "",
  "anObj": {
    "a1": "",
    "a2": "",
    "a3": "",
    "a4": "",
    "a5": "",
    "a6": "",
    "a7": "",
    "a8": "",
    "b1": "",
    "b2": "",
    "b3": "",
    "b4": "",
    "b5": "",
    "b6": "",
    "b7": "",
    "b8": "",
    "c1": "",
    "c2": "",
    "c3": "",
    "c4": "",
    "c5": "",
    "c6": "",
    "c7": "",
    "c8": "",
    "d1": "",
    "d2": "",
    "d3": "",
    "d4": "",
    "d5": "",
    "d6": "",
    "d7": "",
    "d8": "",
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JSON data**

1. There is issues in the json data you provided:

- You forgot to put a brace at the end
- It shouldn't have a comma at the end

Your json should look like this:

```
{
  "serialNumber": "",
  "anObj": {
    "a1": "",
    "a2": "",
    "a3": "",
    "a4": ""
  }
}
```

2. I suggest to represent data in another way, there is no need to put the line and column names (a1, a2,...) that can be generated from the code.

You can represent table in a matrix:

```
List matrix = [
 ["", ""],
 ["", ""],
];
```

As you also need a serial number, one json object could look like this:

```
{
  "serialNumber": "",
  "table": [
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""]
  ]
}
```

I see that there can be many data so you can put it in an array and the json that will finally be:

```
[
    {
      "serialNumber": "",
      "table": [
        ["", "", ""],
        ["", "", ""],
        ["", "", ""]
      ]
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "",
      "table": [
        ["", "", ""],
        ["", "", ""],
        ["", "", ""]
      ]
    }
]
```

**The dart object**

Here is the class to represent the data in Flutter with a method to get the data from json

```
class MyObject {

  String serialNumber;
  List table;

  MyObject(this.serialNumber, this.table);

  // get from json
  MyObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : serialNumber = json['serialNumber'],
        table = json['table'];

}
```

**Parse the data**

Let's assume that you have your json data in an asset file called *assets/data.json* here is how you can parse the data to objects

```
List<MyObject> objects = [];
// get objects from json asset
String asset = 'assets/data.json';
String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(asset);
List<dynamic> list = jsonDecode(data);
for (Map<String, dynamic> map in list) {
  MyObject object = MyObject.fromJson(map);
  objects.add(object);
  print('${object.serialNumber} - ${object.table}');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer..

Comment: if my table list user can insert data in every table cell and save.. how to code it

Comment: You can check these two packages https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_editable_table https://pub.dev/packages/crud_table