# add dynamic table row value list

Tags: flutter, dart, arraylist

I try to add dynamic table row list value but it display this error when I click `Add Box` to add table list.

`Another exception was thrown: type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<List<dynamic>, dynamic>' in type cast`.

```
Container(
            // add button
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[500], width: 1.5)),
            height: data.size.width * 0.039,
            child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Map<List, dynamic> rowValue = Map<List, dynamic>();
                    rowValue = [
                      {
                        'serialNo': '',
                        "table": [
                          [
                            {'first_a': ''},
                            {'Second_a': ''},
                            {'Third_a': ''},
                            {'Fourth_a': ''},
                            {'Fifth_a': ''},
                            {'Sixth_a': ''},
                            {'Seventh_a': ''},
                            {'Eighth_a': ''}
                          ],
                          [
                            {'first_b': ''},
                            {'Second_b': ''},
                            {'Third_b': ''},
                            {'Fourth_b': ''},
                            {'Fifth_b': ''},
                            {'Sixth_b': ''},
                            {'Seventh_b': ''},
                            {'Eighth_b': ''}
                          ],
                          [
                            {'first_c': ''},
                            {'Second_c': ''},
                            {'Third_c': ''},
                            {'Fourth_c': ''},
                            {'Fifth_c': ''},
                            {'Sixth_c': ''},
                            {'Seventh_c': ''},
                            {'Eighth_c': ''}
                          ],
                          [
                            {'first_d': ''},
                            {'Second_d': ''},
                            {'Third_d': ''},
                            {'Fourth_d': ''},
                            {'Fifth_d': ''},
                            {'Sixth_d': ''},
                            {'Seventh_d': ''},
                            {'Eighth_d': ''}
                          ],
                        ]
                      }
                    ] as Map<List, dynamic>;
                    print("get value new");
                    print(rowValue);
                    this.rowList.add(rowValue);
                    // updateDetails();
                  });
                },
                child: Text('+ Add Box',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: data.size.width * 0.019))),
          ),
        ]));
```

this is my full code in [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=dd53beba0ce00e2b4b077b3727436ee6)

every table cell user can insert data. And this question continue from this [make model of array object in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321057/make-model-of-array-object-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

Declared type and assigned data type are different. Declared type is `Map<List, dynamic>` and the data being assigned is `List<Map<String, Object>>`

Since there's only one map in `rowValue` data list, we may remove the list type as well as the cast, cause we don't need to cast the type.

This should work.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> rowValue = <String, dynamic>{};

            rowValue = {
              'serialNo': '',
              "table": [
                [
                  {'first_a': ''},
                  {'Second_a': ''},
                  {'Third_a': ''},
                  {'Fourth_a': ''},
                  {'Fifth_a': ''},
                  {'Sixth_a': ''},
                  {'Seventh_a': ''},
                  {'Eighth_a': ''}
                ],
                [
                  {'first_b': ''},
                  {'Second_b': ''},
                  {'Third_b': ''},
                  {'Fourth_b': ''},
                  {'Fifth_b': ''},
                  {'Sixth_b': ''},
                  {'Seventh_b': ''},
                  {'Eighth_b': ''}
                ],
                [
                  {'first_c': ''},
                  {'Second_c': ''},
                  {'Third_c': ''},
                  {'Fourth_c': ''},
                  {'Fifth_c': ''},
                  {'Sixth_c': ''},
                  {'Seventh_c': ''},
                  {'Eighth_c': ''}
                ],
                [
                  {'first_d': ''},
                  {'Second_d': ''},
                  {'Third_d': ''},
                  {'Fourth_d': ''},
                  {'Fifth_d': ''},
                  {'Sixth_d': ''},
                  {'Seventh_d': ''},
                  {'Eighth_d': ''}
                ],
              ]
            };

          
            this.rowList.add(rowValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data and the type of this parameter doesn't match. From your code examplt, I will focus the value of the `rowValue` and I assume you set the wrong type. Try to change the type of the rowValue like `List<Map<String,dynamic>> rowValue`.

Comment: when change to `List<Map<String,dynamic>> rowValue` it give error `A value of type 'Map<List<dynamic>, dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'.`

Comment: @Fash Can you try with only `Map`? I think it is just the wrong type. Your dart pad link looks strange. (ex. setState in stateless) So, I can't try this code. But I tried with some of your code and it worked with using `List<Map<String, dynamic>> rowValue = [];` for `List<dynamic> rowList = [];`. Your code is really strange for an example, your code is using rowList with `...this.rowList.map((row) { //using row as Map type ex. row['serialNo'], but this row is a List of Map. You can fix it by using this.rowList.addAll(rowValue); instead of .add }`.

Comment: @Fash try replacing Map<List<dynamic>, dynamic> to List<Map<String,dynamic>>

Answer (score 0):

The declared type of **rowValue** is **Map<List, dynamic>**，but the type of the following value is **List**
You can modify the code

```
Map<List, dynamic> rowValue = Map<List, dynamic>();
    rowValue = {
  'serialNo': '',
  "table": [
    [
      {'first_a': ''},
      {'Second_a': ''},
      {'Third_a': ''},
      {'Fourth_a': ''},
      {'Fifth_a': ''},
      {'Sixth_a': ''},
      {'Seventh_a': ''},
      {'Eighth_a': ''}
    ],
    [
      {'first_b': ''},
      {'Second_b': ''},
      {'Third_b': ''},
      {'Fourth_b': ''},
      {'Fifth_b': ''},
      {'Sixth_b': ''},
      {'Seventh_b': ''},
      {'Eighth_b': ''}
    ],
    [
      {'first_c': ''},
      {'Second_c': ''},
      {'Third_c': ''},
      {'Fourth_c': ''},
      {'Fifth_c': ''},
      {'Sixth_c': ''},
      {'Seventh_c': ''},
      {'Eighth_c': ''}
    ],
    [
      {'first_d': ''},
      {'Second_d': ''},
      {'Third_d': ''},
      {'Fourth_d': ''},
      {'Fifth_d': ''},
      {'Sixth_d': ''},
      {'Seventh_d': ''},
      {'Eighth_d': ''}
    ],
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is because of a type mismatch when you're trying to assign a List<Map<String, Object>> to a Map<List, dynamic>.

It looks like you want to add a list of rows to your rowList, and each row is represented as a map with a key 'table' containing a list of lists of maps. You can fix the code as follows:

this looks valid

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    Map<String, dynamic> rowValue = {
      'serialNo': '',
      'table': [
        [
          {'first_a': ''},
          {'Second_a': ''},
          {'Third_a': ''},
          {'Fourth_a': ''},
          {'Fifth_a': ''},
          {'Sixth_a': ''},
          {'Seventh_a': ''},
          {'Eighth_a': ''}
        ],
        [
          {'first_b': ''},
          {'Second_b': ''},
          {'Third_b': ''},
          {'Fourth_b': ''},
          {'Fifth_b': ''},
          {'Sixth_b': ''},
          {'Seventh_b': ''},
          {'Eighth_b': ''}
        ],
        // ... similar rows ...
      ]
    };

    this.rowList.add(rowValue);
  });
},
```